# Bluetooth Not Working on 14.10 with BCM43142

Tags: networking, bluetooth, broadcom, 14.10

thanks for the help. Anyways, as the title says I have the Broadcom43142 chip for Wifi & Bluetooth. It is a dual-chip, it contains both WiFi and Bluetooth. *Groans 
Here is the output from  `dmesg | grep -i blue`

```
[   18.505736] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.19
[   18.505761] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   18.505768] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   18.505771] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   18.505780] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   18.822995] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[   18.823006] bluetooth hci0: Falling back to user helper
[   18.823767] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: patch brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd not found
[   28.385656] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   28.385661] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   28.385669] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   28.850708] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   28.850718] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   28.850725] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  384.623505] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1003 tx timeout
```

All help is appreciated! Also, I have installed the Bluez drivers. All of them.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution.

You need to search for a `.hex` file from a Windows installation, I found mine in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\BCM43142A0_001.001.011.0197.0231.hex`; find the one that starts with `BCM43142A0.`

Then you need to convert it to hcd format. You can find the tool at https://github.com/jessesung/hex2hcd.

```
git clone git://github.com/jessesung/hex2hcd.git
cd hex2hcd
make
hex2hcd <input_file>.hex fw-xxxx_yyyy.hcd
```

Insted of `fw-xxxx_yyyy.hcd` you should use `BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd`.

Then copy the generated hcd file to /lib/firmware/brcm/ and restart.

That should fix the issue.

Comment: Download **.hex** from http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/BLUETOOTH/Broadcom/Broadcom-43142-Bluetooth-40-Adapter-Driver-12007030-for-Windows-8.shtml#download Use *Open with Archive Manager*, and extract last hex file (ending in **.0122.0156.hex**).

Comment: Confirmed for both **14.10** (64-bit) and **15.04** (64-bit).

Comment: Confirmed works for **14.04.2 LTS** (64-bit). *However, it took a couple of re-boots (and **`sudo modprobe -r b43 && sudo modprobe b43`**) before it stopped giving **hci0:** timeout/failed errors.*